# How can I hide a window while keeping it on the taskbar and the Alt+Tab list?

Tags: windows, delphi

In Delphi I can do something like:

```
var
   hWin : HWnd;

 hWin := GetForegroundWindow;
 ShowWindow(hWin, SW_HIDE);
```

and hide the window of the topmost application. The problem is that this also hides the application from the task bar and the alt-tab window.

Is there any way to *only* hide the window without hiding the app from the taskbar and the alt-tab?

Thanks, code is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var
   hWin : Cardinal;

 hWin := GetForegroundWindow;
 ShowWindow(hWin, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED);
```

try this!

Comment: that would minimize it. I don't want that. I just want to hide the window. If it's minimize all kind of messages never reach the application

Comment: what do you mean by "all kind of messages"? i don't think there is a way to hide the window without minimizing it or hiding at all. you can set transparency to 100% may be :), but it sounds freaky.

Comment: Some window messages are not captured by the application when its state is set to minimized. In any case, it doesn't matter. I'll accept your answer since I know that this is not possible in windows

Answer (score 1):

i think you just want to minimize it ... that hides the window and leaves it in the taskbar, no?

Comment: I can't do that. I just want to hide the window. If it's minimize all kind of messages never reach the application

Answer (score 1):

using the following code, you can minimize the window:

```
SendMessage(hWin,WM_SYSCOMMAND,SC_MINIMIZE,0);
```

Comment: that would minimize it. I don't want that. I just want to hide the window. If it's minimized all kind of messages never reach the application

Answer (score 0):

You could resize the window to 0x0, or maybe move it off the screen.  The problem is then if someone alt-tabs to it you would need to restore its position and size.